# Spring Security - httpSecurity.AddFilterBefore intellij IDEA complaining

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have overriden configure method in WebSecurityConfig class,

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity
            .csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

    httpSecurity
            .addFilterBefore(new AuthenticationTokenFilter(),  UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

Intellij is complaining about the addFilterBefore

```
java.lang.Class<? extends java.servlet.Filter in HttpSecurity cannot be applied
```

my AuthenticationTokenFilter

```
public class AuthenticationTokenFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter  {

public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
}
```

UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter which in turn extends GenericFilterBean and end up implementing Filter anyway. No sure if I should cast the filter
See screen grab - apologies for the bad MSPaint work.
[image]

Comment: Your code looks correct. Does it compile by Maven (or whatever build system you have)? Sometimes I see a glitch in Idea: it says some generic-related code is incorrect alghough it is correct. You could try to extract both `addFilterBefore()` parameters as local variables (`Filter filter = new AuthenticationTokenFilter()`, `Class<? extends Filter> clazz = UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class`), then `addFilterBefore(filter, clazz)`, and if it makes Idea happy, inline both variables.

Comment: @RomanPuchkovskiy yes you are right it is a glitch, I did what you said and the error disappeared. I will mark it as the correct answer if you can post it. thanks

Comment: Reposted as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks correct.

Sometimes I see a glitch in Idea: it says some generic-related code is incorrect alghough it is correct. You could try to do the following:

A. Extract both `addFilterBefore()` parameters as local variables:

```
Filter filter = new AuthenticationTokenFilter();
Class<? extends Filter> clazz = UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
```

B. `addFilterBefore(filter, clazz)`

C. If it makes Idea happy, inline both variables.

Comment: Also I must mention that I had the java compiler to 1.5 damn Intellij automation, I set it to 1.8 and I can write it like before  `.addFilterBefore(new AuthenticationTokenFilter(),  UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);`